# Motor Control Reverse Current Diode

Tags: motor, diodes, control

I'm having an intermittent issue with a motor control setup I'm working on. I'm using a [Pololu G2 18v17](https://www.pololu.com/product/2991) motor driver controlled simply with an Arduino. I have a current limiting resistor installed on the motor driver which sets the maximum output to 10A per the datasheet. The driver offers a lot more control than I'm using in this case.

My setup is to drive the required pins low/high to engage the controller and then an external pressure switch actually turns the motor on and off. This is really just giving me current limiting. (I'm sure there's a better way to do this and less expensive, but not the focus of my question).

I'm seeing an issue when the motor turns off that my whole system resets. I was thinking it might be a reverse voltage issue, but the driver datasheet lists reverse voltage protection. Am I negating that protection with the way I'm using it? Should I add an additional diode at the power supply?

Comment: Have you got a circuit diagram of the controller?

Comment: Unfortunately not @andy aka. I've asked them for one in the past, but they don't share them.

Comment: Yes V=Ldi/dt on motor shutdown can create high E fields which can be picked by high impedance input cables or ground shift.  So reverse diodes are needed.

Comment: Thanks, @Sunnyskyguy EE75. Only diodes I have sitting around are 1N4004. I'm going to have to pick up something beefier. This motor draws ~3A when running, but ~15A in rush. Should I install it in parallel with the motor with reverse polarity?

EDIT: Could you suggest an appropriate diode?

Comment: Would this be an appropriate diode? https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/comchip-technology/6A04-G/641-1317-1-ND/1979682

Comment: You want me to guess your L/R vs 5xTau ratio with deadtime?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a ton of information available on the motor. If you can guess something that would have a decent margin of safety, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I'm going to see if I have a frequency generator around so I can characterize the motor....

Comment: https://www.pololu.com/product/2991. Also ensure you have a low ESR xxx uF cap near driver , not having could also cause issues.  With dV/dt

Comment: I have a 470uF/50V cap installed on the driver.

Comment: Small RF snubber caps 100pF could be tried in various places and ensure good grounds

Comment: Managed to rig up a voltage generator and characterize the motor. I'm coming up with T= 7.4us, and R = 2.5. Assuming those are realistic, that's L= 1.85*10^-5. Seem reasonable? (My multimeter jumped around for a while, I just let it sit connected for a bit and it settled at 2.5 ohms)